# Keep a modified version of a GitHub repository updated

Tags: github, mongoose

Over the last few days, I have been working on adding update validators to Mongoose. I consider this absolutely critical in the way I use mongodb; this is why I got myself a lot of sleep deprivation, and implemented it:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/pull/1256

For reasons that are *very* legitimate (it's impossible to have 100% consistent validators as right now mongoose validators expect full access to the loaded doc, something that is impossible for an update), Aaron, the great Mongoose maintainer, might end up not accepting this upstream. See the discussion in the pull request if you are interested.

This is absolutely not a problem: Mongoose is Aaron's baby, and he obviously got a LOT of things right; at the same time... well, I do do need update validation.

I am hopeless with git, although I am getting the gist of it. Now, I cloned Mongoose's main repo so that I could submit my pull request:

https://github.com/mercmobily/mongoose

I am obviously using this one for development (since it has the goodies). The modifications are really quite localised (only a big chunk of code in model.js and two small localised chunks in query.js). But, I am worried because Mongoose is very actively developed and I don't really want to miss out on the latest cream.

So, the question: How can I keep my repository syncronised with the main one, on a day to day basis? Or maybe weekly basis? Merging my modifications should be straightforward, as they shouldn't affect Mongoose as a whole.

I hope I won't have to do it in the end, but I am preparing for the worst :D

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, Merc! Don't forget to accept Ivan's answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way you keep up with changes in a remote repo is that you 1) add a new "remote" repo in your local git repo, 2) fetch updates for that new remote repo, and 3) merge/rebase your repo to these changes.

Check these articles out:
[How to sync with a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313125/how-to-sync-with-a-remote-git-repository)
http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/11/pull-with-rebase.html