# GitHub: I need to update an existing repository

Tags: git, github

Recently I started a repository for an Open-edX project that I have to do at school.  However rather than forking the edX-platform repository I downloaded the master zip and created another public repository where I can manage pull requests that I make. Maybe in the future I will be a contributor.  I would like to know If doing "git remote add upstream https://github.com/edx/edx-platform.git" to my repository would cause conflicts with the files from the master zip I downloaded. I would have to try this but I would like to know if anyone has had this experience doing so with repositories?  In the end I would like to be able to:

git fetch upstream

git checkout master

git merge upstream/master

git push origin master

I saw this post [Keep a modified version of a GitHub repository updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985407/keep-a-modified-version-of-a-github-repository-updated) . Is this the idea?

Thanks.
Edward

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this will fail and you will never be able to re-unite these repositories (the original one, and your fresh start).

This is because a commit hash id takes into account all the history that lead there. I suppose your own repository basically consists of only the first commit with all these files. Which is: They have no history, so even if you might be able to get the exact same files from the original repository, the hash is different because of different parent commits, different commit messages, and differen delta in the files in this commit.

If you think contributing to the original later might be a good idea, why don't you just fork or clone the original repository? Even if adding that repo as another remote would work seamlessly, you would end in exactly the same situation: You have your own repo that is connected to the original - where is the difference between your way of doing it, and simply cloning it and then create the branches you like locally?

Comment: I could definitely check out what your saying with a dummy repository and see what happens.