# How to get a new branch in my fork from the original repository?

Tags: git

I forked a repo and the original repo has gotten a new branch after I forked it.

```
OriginalRepo
   |
   +-BranchA
   |
   +-newBranch


MyFork
   |
   +-BranchA
```

I want to get the branch newBranch into my fork, how can I do this?

Comment: Add the remote, thus fetch it. See https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork/ and https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/ for further details.

Comment: Anyway, possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313125/how-to-sync-with-a-remote-git-repository

Comment: The suggested solution in the proposed duplicate didn't solve my problem. So that's why I asked. If all I had to do was git pull it would have been no problem at all

Comment: Try going down of another couple of responses... :-)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
git remote add OriginalRepo repository-URL
git fetch OriginalRepo
git checkout newBranch
git push origin newBranch
```

Comment: this worked I just had to also do this to get the branch up into my fork "git push origin newBranch"

Comment: Is this possible in GitHub UI?