# How to import project from local machine to already created repo in bit bucket

Tags: bitbucket

Want to import ParseParcel .NET project from my local machine to existing created repository in bit bucket(trade Me/Tech Tests/parseparcel) and I have gone through https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/importing-code-from-an-existing-project-776640909.html. But no luck. Please guide me. I have followed below step but getting "**git remote add origin https://git@bitbucket.org/anu/trade Me/Tech Tests/parsetheparcel-rajesh-yadav.git usage: git remote add [] -f, --fetch fetch the remote branches --tags import all tags and associated objects when fetching or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags) -t, --track branch(es) to track -m, --master master branch --mirror[=] set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from**" Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new repo in bitbucket - > copy the https link provided.

open git bash in your project folder -> follow these commands

1. git init
2. git add --all
3. git commit -m "Initial Commit"
4. git remote add origin https://username@your.bitbucket.domain:7999/yourproject/repo.git  --paste copied link here
5. git push -u origin master

Comment: I have already created repo in bit bucket. Now, i want is to import project from my local machine to this existing repo.

Comment: You can also check whether all your files are committed using command -> git status

Comment: When I pass "git remote add origin https://git@bitbucket.org/anu/trade Me/Tech Tests/parsetheparcel-rajesh-yadav.git", It shows something like  "-f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
    --tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                          or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
                          master branch
    --mirror[=<push|fetch>]
                          set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from"

Comment: And when check git log " commit 31e5aca0e8cb109728cb2e79612387c4c51c4538
Author: Anu <raj.yadav82@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 5 10:13:48 2017 +1200

    Intial commit

commit cd699937708fc7f80bc288ec62029176a77635ff
Author: Anu <raj.yadav82@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 31 23:47:26 2017 +1200

    This is my First commit" but when i check in repository this commit is not displaying into my bit bucket.

Comment: i think you have to sync your local repo with bitbucket. Follow the steps given  in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313125/how-to-sync-with-a-remote-git-repository

Comment: Please mark it as the answer if it really helped you