# git p4 push p4 repo to GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, push, perforce

I have been trying to get `git p4` working and I must be missing something silly. I have scoured countless websites and all basically say the same thing including this one: [How to sync with a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313125/how-to-sync-with-a-remote-git-repository).

I would like to set up my flow so that I can push content from my p4 server to Git. I don't really care if it's automatic, I just want to upload files.

Here are the commands I ran, the git-p4.py is aliased to p4git.

```
git init DL; cd DL/
git config --global alias.p4 '!git-p4'
git config --global git-p4.detectRenames true
git config --global git-p4.detectCopies true
git config --add p4git.branchList main:DL
p4git clone --use-client-spec //depot/apps/DevOps/tools/ansible/DL/...@all .
```

That works, from what I can tell a git local repo gets populated. That's fine and dandy but how do I get my p4 content INTO GitHub or GitLab? There are so many sites talking about cloning and then immediately talks about importing into p4.

Shouldn't there be additional commands for something like this?

```
git push origin git@gitlab.domain.com:user/sandbox.git
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have created an empty GitHub repository, all you need to do locally is:

```
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote add gh https://github.com/<your>/<NewEmptyREpo>
git push gh master
```

The [OP New2Python](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6611818/new2python) prefers ([in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61472134/git-p4-push-p4-repo-to-gitlab/61473378?noredirect=1#comment108770084_61473378)), since `git-p4` reveals to be capricious:

> I just manually copied files in repo and used normal git commands.

Comment: Unfortunately that just gave me: `To gitlab.domain.com:user/sandbox.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.domain.com:user/sandbox.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: ran more commands from other sites: `git remote add gh git@gitlab.domain.com:user/sandbox.git
git push gh master
git pull git@gitlab.domain.com:user/sandbox.git
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
git pull master --allow-unrelated-histories
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories
git add DL
git commit -m "First commit"
git remote -v
git remote add origin  git@gitlab.domain.com:user/sandbox.git
git remote -v
git push origin master
git fetch gh
git checkout master
git push gh master
git pull gh master
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories`

Comment: That means your gitlab repo is not empty. Create an empty one.

Comment: FYI the `domain` and `user` are substitutes for real values

Comment: I had that README.md file which I deleted but same errors.

Comment: @New2Python Exactly: recreate a new empty repo, without README. Deleting in the current one is not enough, you need to create a new empty repository.

Comment: the git p4 utility is messing with the local git repo somehow...abandoning this seems to painful. I just manually copied files in repo and used normal git commands... sadness.

Comment: @New2Python I agree. At least, your solution would work too. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.