# Remote ref changes

Tags: git

Suppose we have a branchA. The last commit in its remote version was by me, say c1.
Then somebody did some changes (based on a patch that I provided) and pushed on the remote (or rather "updated" my commit c1).
Now I wanted to sync the remote with my local branch, and I did `git fetch origin` but then I saw the message

```
Your branch and 'origin/branchA' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

The way that I solved it was by executing `git reset --hard HEAD~1` and then I run
`git fetch origin && git merge`
which brought me to the desired position of being in sync with the remote.
My question is: was that a correct handling? If not, what would be the optimal?

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD~1` was unnecessary (or even harmful, you lost your most recent local commit), `fetch` & `merge` is the correct method (which is equivalent to `pull`, as is suggested in the message).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sync with a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313125/how-to-sync-with-a-remote-git-repository)

Comment: Well no, because then I would have to make a new commit with the changes. I *didn't* want to make a new commit. I wanted to "update" my last commit.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your situation exactly. But apparently you have the desired result so you did it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody can update any commit.  That means they didn't, and you won't either.

You can, however, have the *illusion* of updating some commit.  It's an illusion!  It did not really happen!  Always remember that, otherwise none of this makes any sense.

*Git* finds a commit by hash ID.  The hash ID of some commit depends on the exact content of the commit.  Once you, or whoever, has made the commit, *that* hash ID means *that* commit.  It means that now.  It means that tomorrow.  It means that next year.  It *always* means that commit, and no other commit, ever.

*Humans*, however, don't use hash IDs.  (Quick: what are the hash IDs of the last ten commits you made?  I don't know any of mine either.  I don't even remember the special [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) hash ID.)  Humans use branch names: *I made a commit on `branchA`*.  That's what you said, more or less.

We have Git store hash IDs in branch names.  *Your* `branchA` stored the hash ID of your commit.  Then you gave your commit, with its permanently-assigned forever ID, to some other Git in charge of some other repository.  Because every Git computes hash IDs the same way, *their* hash ID for that commit was the *same hash ID*.  They put that in *their* repository and it had the same hash ID and they set up *their* name `branchA` to record the same big ugly hash ID.

Later, someone—not you—came along and squinted hard at that particular commit and said something like: *Hah, I can do better!*  They took that commit *off* of *their* `branchA`—the `branchA` that is in that other Git repository that you have your Git talk to; *your* Git uses the name `origin/branchA` for this—using some Git command, perhaps `git reset --hard HEAD~1`.  We don't know, or really care for that matter, exactly what Git command they used.

Having ripped that commit off that branch—it's still there in their Git repository, it's just not at the end of that branch now—they then added their "new and improved" version of that commit to *their* `branchA`.  We can draw that situation, that occurs in their Git repository, like this:

```
          H   <-- ???
         /
...--F--G--I   <-- branchA
```

The uppercase letters here stand in for the actual Git hash IDs (which we don't know, or really care about that much since we never memorize any of them).  Your commit `H`, which *used to be* the last commit on `branchA`, is now floating free in space, with no *name* that finds it.  Their new-and-improved version of your commit, which we're calling `I`, is now the *last* commit on *their* `branchA`.

#### This is not how Git is supposed to be used

Suppose for a moment that they had not torn your commit out by the roots, and instead, just *added* a commit.  (This is how Git *is* supposed to be used, in general.)  If they had done that, *their* Git repository would now have this sequence of commits in it:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- branchA
```

That is, they'd have a new commit `I`, but the *parent* of commit `I` would be your commit `H`.  Their name `branchA` would remember the hash ID of their commit `I`, and their commit `I` would remember the hash ID of your commit `H`.

You would then be able to run:

```
git fetch origin
```

which, in your own Git repository, would result in this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- branchA
            \
             I   <-- origin/branchA
```

Remember, your Git uses the name `origin/branchA` to remember the hash ID they're remembering with their name `branchA`.  The things that actually matter to Git are the *commits* with their *commit hash IDs*, but Git gives us these names to help us *find* the hash IDs.  Each repository has *its own names:* their name `branchA` is for *them* to use, and your name `branchA` is for *you* to use.

Had they added a commit on like this, you could then have your Git "slide your name forward" (and down) so that you would have, in your repository:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- branchA, origin/branchA
```

Your Git and their Git would now both agree that the *last* commit in the branch named `branchA` is commit `I` (whatever its actual hash ID is).  Your Git would hang on to your own name `branchA` *and* your name `origin/branchA`, but both would now point to existing commit `I`.

If you need to fix up commit `I`, you simply add a *new* commit `J` to *your* repository:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- origin/branchA
               \
                J   <-- branchA
```

Note how your new commit points back to the (now-shared) existing commit `I`, which *adds on*.  You can now have your Git send new commit `J` back, and ask them to set their `branchA` name to point to commit `J`.

#### Faking it: the illusion of changing or removing commits

This is the normal way to use Git: everyone *adds* commits to the collection, and nobody *takes any way*.  Some people find this messy (because it *is* messy) and prefer to fake things as if the development happened much more cleanly.  There's nothing really *wrong* with that.  If commits `H` and `I` have no real value, and only commit `J` should remain, we don't need to preserve `H` and `I` for all time: we can make a new and improved commit that's *like* `J`, but that has `G` as its parent:

```
          H--I--J   <- ???
         /
...--F--G--J'  <-- branchA
```

(in your Git repository, with `origin/branchA` not shown).  Suppose we now send commit `J'` to the *other* Git, and *force* it to set its name `branchA` to point to `J'`.  Then they, too, will have:

```
          H--I--J   <-- ???
         /
...--F--G--J'  <-- branchA
```

in *their* Git repository.  Anyone who looks up commits by name only, and uses the name `branchA`, will see commit `J'`, and from `J'`, will reach back to commit `G`.  It is as if commits `H` and `I` and `J` never happened.

If you have the hash IDs of commits `H`, `I`, and `J` memorized, or written down on paper or a whiteboard or something, you can still find these commits for as long as they stick around in each Git repository.  How long that is depends on a number of factors.  A standard "ordinary user" Git repository keeps these commits for at least 30 days by default.  But if you don't *know* their hash IDs, how will you *find* these commits?  The name `branchA` won't let you find them, because the way Git works, it turns a branch name into the hash ID of the *last* commit on the branch, and then works backwards from there.  The commit that comes before `J'` is `G`.  It's not the hash ID of any of the now-invisible commits.

This is what you and your co-worker are doing.  I do not know why you are doing it.  If you both like it, you can keep doing it.  It's more difficult and error-prone than just adding new commits, and it's easy to completely lose a commit, if you don't know all the secret ways of finding lost commits.  I don't recommend working this way—but if you want to, now you know what you are doing.