# out of sync origin and master

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a git repo that has two files on `master` (e.g. when I go onto GitHub.com) and a git repo locally on my computer (`origin`) with many, many files. There are several files on `origin` that are not on master, and I have made changes to the README on `master` that I have not updated in `origin`.

I wanted to `git push` select scripts from origin to master.

however, I get the error

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally."
```

So, I wanted to `git pull` what I have on `master` but I'm apprehensive to do this because I do not want to lose all my work that I have locally.

I was thinking of saving all my work in `origin` elsewhere, doing `git pull` into origin , then moving the work back into origin and doing `git push <files>`.

is there any other less circuitous way of doing this?

If anything, I rather remove everything from `master` since there's literally two files there and then add everything I need from `origin`, but I dont know if directionally based on how git works that'll be alright.

thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sync with a remote Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313125/how-to-sync-with-a-remote-git-repository)

Comment: `git pull` and then `git push` should work in most non-exotic cases. `git pull` will not lose any work.

Comment: to make sure im understanding this correctly `git pull` will only update the same files that are shared between `master` and `origin`? so all my other files are safe?

Comment: If the output of `git status` is that you have no uncommitted changes then you are safe (presumably `git pull` may even refuse to run otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

This is my recommendation:  Don't start with `git pull`.  Start with `git fetch`.  Work with `git fetch` and other Git commands for a while, until you really "get" what `git fetch` and the other Git commands do.  **Then** you're ready to use `git pull`, if you choose, because `git pull` simply means:

1. run `git fetch`; then
2. run a second Git command, usually `git merge`, but you can choose `git rebase` instead.

This makes `git pull` a convenient shortcut, because it turns out that after `git fetch`, you very often want a `git merge` or `git rebase`.  But I often like to stick a `git log` or other command *in between*, and when using `git pull`, you *can't* do that.  It turns out the convenience command is ... inconvenient.

The bigger problem newbies have with `git pull` is that it seems to be Magic.  This makes it impossible to think about what's really happening.  I had this same problem for a while when I first used Git about 15 years ago.  Learning that I could separate `git pull` into `git fetch` + second command was one of the keys to understanding Git.

#### Things to know

The things you need to know include the following:

- Git is not about *files*, but rather about *commits*.  So you need to look at which *commits* you have, and which *commits* some other Git repository (such as the one over on `origin`) has.
- Commits *contain* files.  In fact, every commit has a *full snapshot of every file*.  These are stored in a compressed, read-only, Git-only format, that only Git can read and literally nothing—not even Git itself—can overwrite.  Once a file is saved in a commit, then, it's *completely safe inside that commit*.  **Nothing** can change it.  As long as you still have that *commit*, you still have that *file* too.
- But this in turn means that the files that you can *see and work on / with* are **not in Git**.  The files you see and work on are ordinary, read/write files.  Since the files inside a Git commit *aren't* ordinary files, these must be *different* files.  And that's just what they are.  When you use `git checkout` or the newfangled `git switch`, you pick out some commit, from some branch, that Git should *copy out*.  Git finds all the files that are inside that commit and copies them out to your work area, which Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*.

Once you have a solid grasp of this, you then need to realize a few more things:

- Git makes *new* commits, not from what you have in your working tree, but rather from what *Git* has in *Git's index*.  This thing—"the index"—has two more names: it's also called the *staging area*, and sometimes—rarely these days, mostly in flags like `--cached`—the *cache*.  (Why it has three names is a little bit of a mystery, but *staging area* is the newest of the three names and also the most descriptive, so it's clear that at least part of the reason is that the original names were bad.)

  You can think of Git's index as your *proposed next commit*.  When you first check out some particular commit with `git checkout` or `git switch`, Git copies the entire commit *into* the index / staging-area.  So now the proposed next commit, and the current commit, and your working tree, all have the same files.  There are therefore *three* copies of each file lying around:

  1. the unchangeable, saved-forever copy in the current commit, which is totally safe from changes because it's in a commit;
  2. the proposed-next-commit copy in Git's index, which you *can* change; and
  3. the copy you can see and edit, in your working tree.

  What all this means is that you do your work in your working tree, and then you run `git add` on any files you updated.  You can run it on every file (`git add .`) or tell Git to find updated files (`git add -u`) if you like: these tell Git *figure out what I changed*, more or less.  Or you can just run it directly on a file you just changed.  What `git add` is *doing* here is copying the updated, working-tree copy of the file *back into Git's index*.  This changes the *proposed next commit*.
- When you run `git status`:

  - Git compares the current commit (`HEAD`) to the index / staging-area.  Any differences between these two are `staged for commit`, i.e., this is what's *different* between `HEAD` and the proposed next commit.  The new commit will still be a full snapshot of *every* file, but only *some* files are *changed*.
  - Separately, Git compares the index / staging-area to your working tree.  Any differences between these two are `not staged for commit`.  That is, you could run `git add` on *these* changes, to update the proposed-next-commit copy of the file, which might change the output from the earlier `HEAD`-vs-index diff.
- When you run `git commit`, Git just packages up whatever is in Git's index *at that time* and uses that to make the new commit.
- A *branch name* like `master` just helps Git find some specific commit.  When you're *on* `master` and run `git commit`, Git:

  1. packages up the files in its index;
  2. adds your name, email address, etc., to make a commit out of all of this;
  3. writes out the new commit; and
  4. makes the *name* `master` identify the *new* commit.

  The new commit links back to what *was* the last commit, before.

#### A mental image of commits

What all this means is that we can *draw* what's happening, which I find very helpful.  Let's say we start with a small repository with just a few commits, and just one branch name, `master` or `main`, that identifies the *last* commit in this repository:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

Each commit has a *number*, a big ugly [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) number, that is unique to that one particular commit.  We call this number a *hash ID*.  Making a commit assigns the new commit a hash ID.  *No other commit, in any Git repository—yours or anyone else's—can **ever** have **that** hash ID.*  That's why the number is so big and so ugly that no one can deal with it.

Instead of dealing with the numbers, then, I've used a single uppercase letter to stand in for the numbers.  Here `H` is the hash ID of the *last* commit in branch `master`.  Commit `H` has a permanent, safely-saved snapshot of *every* file.  It also has some metadata—some stuff to say that *you* made it (if you did make it), when you made it, your log message, and so on.  Inside that metadata, Git has added the raw hash ID of *earlier* commit `G`.

We say that commit `H` *points to* earlier commit `G`.  Commit `G`, of course, has a snapshot and metadata.  The metadata tells us who made `G`, when, and why—their log message—and has in it the hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`.  So `G` *points to* `F`.

Commit `F`, of course, has all this same stuff, so it points back to some still-earlier commit, and so on.  This repeats all the way through history—which is nothing but these commits—until we get to the very first commit ever.  It *can't* point backwards to some earlier commit, so it just doesn't, and that's how Git knows that history ends (er, starts?) here.

Note that in all of this, Git works *backwards*.  It has to, because branch names find the *last* commit.  The last commit finds an earlier commit, which finds an even-earlier commit, and so on.

Note that the branch name *points to* the last commit.  To add a *new* commit, then, we just take this string of commits:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

and create a new commit `I` that points back to existing commit `H`:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I
```

If we're *on* branch `master` when we do this, that tells Git: *Now that we have new commit `I`, make the name `master` point to `I`*, which means we get this:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master
```

and now there's no reason to draw `I` on a separate line:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
```

means the same thing.

#### `git fetch`

What `git fetch` does is to call up some other Git and get *commits* from that other Git.  To call up some other Git, we need a URL: `ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git`, or `https://github.com/user/repo.git`, or whatever.  We have Git save that URL for us, under a *name* like `origin`, so that we don't have to keep typing it in all the time.

We then run:

```
git fetch origin
```

or even:

```
git fetch origin master
```

This has our Git call up *their* Git, over at the URL saved under the name `origin`.  Their Git lists out, for our Git, *all* of their branches (and tags and other stuff).<sup>1</sup>  Our Git then picks out any interesting ones—they're all interesting, unless we used the second form where we said *only pay attention to their `master`*—and checks with their Git to see if they have any commits that they have, that we want and don't have.

(This involves using the commit numbers, and is why the commit numbers *must* be unique.  But that's a topic for another discussion.)

In general, Git is greedy: any commit they have that we don't, we want!  Our Git grabs all of their new-to-us commits from them, using the fetch protocol.  Of course, all *our* commits, we already have, and all the commits we got from them earlier, we already have.  Our Git and their Git talk and our Git figures out a good way to get just the *new* stuff, avoiding re-downloading any files even in new commits if we already have those files.  (That is, the fetch goes fast and doesn't fetch stuff we already have, even inside new commits.  That, too, is a topic for another discussion, though.)

Last, once we have these new commits, our Git updates some names that help our Git *keep track* of these new commits.  These are our *remote-tracking names*,<sup>2</sup> of the form `origin/master` for instance.

Suppose that, while we were making commit `I`, *they* acquired some new commit `J`.  So before we do anything—make a commit *or* run `git fetch`—*we* have, in *our* repository, this:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
```

We make our new commit and have:

```
...--G--H   <-- origin/master
         \
          I   <-- master
```

(There's a reason now to put `I` and `master` on a separate line, so that we can have `origin/master` still point to `H`.)

If we now run `git fetch`, we find *they* have a new commit, which we'll get and draw as `J`:

```
          J   <-- origin/master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          I   <-- master
```

Note that commits up through `H` are on *both* of these chains; it's only `I` and `J` that diverge.  We could draw either `I` or `J` on the same line as `H` here, too: I just *chose* to draw `origin/master` on a separate line this time, to emphasize the shared nature of commits up through and including `H`.

**Note that all of these commits are read-only, and none of them are our working-tree files.**  If we have commit `I` checked out, that's fine: that means commit `I` is our current commit, and that Git's index and our working tree match commit `I`, or are getting ready for a new commit, or whatever.  **Adding commit `J` to the repository via `git fetch` has no effect on any work we're doing right now.**  The `git fetch` is quite safe.  We can do this part any time.

---

<sup>1</sup>In a repository with a lot of branches and tags, this can take a lot of time and involve megabytes of data, just for the listing, so the `git fetch origin master` version *can*, in modern Git, limit the listing and speed this up.  This doesn't matter for most repositories, which mostly just have maybe a dozen branches and a few hundred or thousand tags; it's repositories like the one for Chrome, that have 50+ MiB of branch and tag names, where this is a problem.

<sup>2</sup>Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*.  They're our Git's memory of their Git's branch names.  I find the word *branch* redundant here, so I just use the phrase *remote-tracking names*.  Git has lots of kinds of names: branch names, tag names, notes names, `refs/stash`, names it uses temporarily during `git bisect`, and so on.  Remote-tracking names are just another kind of name.  Each name holds just one hash ID—that's how they *all* work, regardless of what kind of name they are.

---

#### It's the *second* command that messes with our working tree files

Now that we have, say:

```
          J   <-- origin/master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

we can run some *second* Git command, like `git pull` would do.  This *second* command will mess with *our* files—the ones in our working tree.

Whether we choose `git merge` or `git rebase`, *both* commands need to be able to overwrite our working tree.  So *now* we need, for sure, to run `git status` and make sure it says that everything is "clean".

The command we choose—merge vs rebase—and exactly what it does, are interesting questions.  There are already plenty of answers about them on StackOverflow though.  Knowing that `git pull` runs `git fetch`—which is safe—and then a *second* command that's *not* "safe" in this same sense, will get you pretty far.

Comment: thank you so much for such a thorough explanation! when I do `git status` before running anything else, it says `On branch master. Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.`

So I think im in the final figure that you’ve drawn, this is my situation
   ```
    J <- origin/master
  /
…—G—H
  \
  I
    \
      L
        \
   M <-master
    ```
So,  `git merge` effectively merges the commits in origin/master with the corresponding files in master?
When I do `git status` I get a ton of red with ‘changed not stages for commit’ and ‘untracked files’

Comment: what do you mean by saying 'make sure it says that everything is "clean"'? I ran `git fetch` and im clearly in your final figure. I want to make sure I get what you're saying before I run `git merge`

Comment: When you run `git status`, you'll see, e.g.: `on branch master` and then `nothing to commit, working tree clean`. **Or** you'll see `on branch master` and then `changes staged for commit` and/or `changes not staged for commit`: so `status` either says *clean*, or, well, doesn't say "clean".

Comment: If you have some changes that aren't committed (and maybe not even changed), that means it's time to figure out what to do with them. Do you still want them? If so, you should probably commit them. There are other options than committing, but that's something to learn later. :-) (Also, the main one is `git stash` and I think `git stash` is ... well, *evil* is too strong, but *has too many complicated corner cases* is accurate.)

Comment: One other thing to experiment with, at various times: run `git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline`. Or leave out the `--all` part. The `--decorate` part is actually the default now (since early Git-version-2 or so) so you can generally leave that out too. The output from `git log` is all descriptive: none of it changes anything in your repository. So it's always safe to look at. It takes a long time to get used to how Git draws the commit graph, though, so it's good to see a lot of examples.

Comment: Anyway, yes, you almost certainly want to add-and-commit stuff at this point. Have a look through some questions about "untracked files": those are files that are not in Git's index / staging-area at all, and hence won't be in your new commit(s). You can then use `git merge` *or* `git rebase`: read up on both of these options. Merge is fundamentally much simpler, but for whatever reasons, many people prefer the more complicated rebase.

Comment: Gah, word-o (like a typo but worse) in a comment from 32 minutes ago: "If you have some changes that are ... maybe not even changed" should read "maybe not even staged". (I have various distractions happening this afternoon...)

Comment: ah, ok this is my confusion about 'clean'... when I ran `git fetch` it says "On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 3 and 4 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)’"
I have multiple changes not staged for commit (I dont care about those files) and I have several untracked files.
so if I do `git merge`, that'll only affect the stuff associated with a commit, right, and all my untracked files are safe, and I can `git add` them after I merge `origin` and `master`?

Comment: Unfortunately, `git merge` may need to write on your working tree. Whether an untracked file is "safe" here is tricky, because *untracked* means *not in Git's index right now*. That doesn't mean it was never in Git's index before, and won't ever be in Git's index afterward. What *will* be in Git's index in the future is partly up to you: when you `git add` a new file, it's in Git's index at that point. When you `git rm` a file, it goes back out of Git's index at that point. But: if the file exists in some *commit*, and you use that commit, the file will also go into Git's index at that point.

Comment: Files that are untracked now and have never been in Git and won't be in Git for a while (or ever) are safe, though. And, if the file *would* be overwritten by merge, `git merge` will say so. There is one bad corner case here, having to do with an untracked file also listed in `.gitignore`, that's in some commit. It's rare and I can never remember offhand whether it can come up during `git merge`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229756/discussion-between-wiscoyogi-and-torek).

Answer (score 0):

let "branch1" be youre current branch.

1. Create a new branch "branch2" and commit all of your local work to that branch.
2. Move back to branch1
3. execute:

   ```
   git fetch
   git pull
   ```
4. now you have branch1 with the latest remote reposetory work, and branch2 with your-local-committed-only branch. you may merge those branches and push your merged branch to the remote server.